# use value as link text in grid,mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using Grid.MVC in my mvc4 application i want to use the value as link text but unable to do that

```
   @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
    {
      columns.Add(c => c.FirstName).Titled("Username").Filterable(true).Sanitized(false)
     .Encoded(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("", "Edit", "Admin", new { Id = 0 }, null).ToHtmlString());
      columns.Add(c => c.Email).Titled("Email");
      columns.Add(c => c.IsBlocked).Titled("Blocked");
      columns.Add(c => c.IsApproved).Titled("Approved");
      columns.Add(c => c.LastLoginDate).Titled("Last Login");
      columns.Add(c => c.RegisterationDate).Titled("Registeration Date");
    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

want to use username as link text and its id what should i have to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case "o" - it is a row in the Model collection, use it to access their properties

```
RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink(o.FirstName, "Edit", "Admin", new { Id = o.id }, null).ToHtmlString());
```